# 0x00000000 hexadecimal?

Tags: numbers, hex

I had always been taught  0–9 to represent values zero to nine, and A, B, C, D, E, F for 10-15.

I see this format 0x00000000 and it doesn't fit into the pattern of hexadecimal. Is there a guide or a tutor somewhere that can explain it?

I googled for hexadecimal but I can't find any explanation of it.

So my 2nd question is, is there a name for the 0x00000000 format?

Comment: `0x0000` is a hexadecimal number. The `0x` indicates that it should be evaluated in base 16 instead of 10. Without it, you'd not know whether `15` is decimal or hexadecimal (or octal). Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Is there a name for that particular format or I have to type in hexadecimal in google hoping that format will show up?

Comment: @nhat `0x` is a standard hex prefix, it simply tells you the following number will be in hex.  A google search shouldnt be necessary(just take what you know about hex and remember that prefix)

Comment: Use the Any Base Calculator on the Android market to convert between bases: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ewe.radixcalculator

Answer (score 28, accepted):

0x simply tells you the number after it will be in hex

so 0x00 is 0, 0x10 is 16, 0x11 is 17 etc

Comment: @nhat it doesnt go by ones, each place is a factor of 16, so for your case it is 8*16 or 128 because the 8 is in the 16's place.

Comment: I noticed 0x00000080 = 0x0080. The formatting what was confusing me but after looking at this more, it starts to make more sense.

Comment: @nhat yea all the leading zero's can be dropped since it is multiplying that power of 16 by zero which doesnt change the result.

Answer (score 15):

The `0x` is just a prefix (used in C and many other programming languages) to mean that the following number is in base 16.

Other notations that have been used for hex include:

```
$ABCD
ABCDh
X'ABCD'
"ABCD"X
```

Comment: cool, thanks for the info. Never saw those formats before. Is there any particular site you learned that from?

Comment: I worked with *all* those notations before there even was an internet. So, no particular web site.

Comment: PHP programmers will identify anything that starts with `$` as a variable, not as a hex value.

Comment: @Arjan: and that's why PHP doesn't use `$` for hex notation.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is hexadecimal.

Otherwise, you can't represent `A`, for example. The compiler for C and Java will treat it as variable identifier. The added prefix `0x` tells the compiler it's hexadecimal number, so:

```
int ten_i = 10;
int ten_h = 0xA;

ten_i == ten_h; // this boolean expression is true
```

The leading zeroes indicate *the size*: `0x0080` hints the number will be stored in *two* bytes; and `0x00000080` represents *four* bytes. Such notation is often used for flags: if a certain bit is set, that feature is enabled.

P.S. As an off-topic note: if the number starts with `0`, then it's interpreted as octal number, for example `010 == 8`. Here `0` is also a prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Everything after the x are hex digits (the 0x is just a prefix to designate hex), representing 32 bits (if you were to put 0xFFFFFFFF in binary, it would be 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111).

Answer (score 1):

hexadecimal digits are often prefaced with 0x to indicate they are hexadecimal digits. 
In this case, there are 8 digits, each representing 4 bits, so that is 32 bits or a word. I"m guessing you saw this in an error, and it is a memory address. this value means null, as the hex value is 0.